# Getting chrome sign in password

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, windows-8.1

Currently, I am signed into chrome, and it is tied to my gmail account.

I do not wish to reset the password to the gmail account, but I do want to find out what it is (somehow, the password I have stored for that is wrong).

Is there a way to recover the password that chrome uses to sign in?

I tried looking under chrome saved passwords and didn't see it.

Comment: Hopefully it isn't possible, because Chrome shouldn't need to store the password itself. It should only store an authorization token generated when you first entered the password.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg 1) isnt that "as good as" the password? 2) is that actually the case?

Comment: I thought Chrome Sign In actually tied in to Google account sign in? So they never did store anything on the Chrome browser itself except as Oliver guessed that it may only be a token generated when you login to gmail/Google the first time (like a session cookie). I don't know if that token can be found and/or moved to a different computer for session jacking, but that may be a good question to security.stackexchange.com (sister/brother site for this place)

Comment: @Darius This question is less about the security implications of the token (if it even is a token) but about how to recover information from chrome and the feasibility of such a thing.

Comment: Well, I'm assuming Chrome uses OAuth2, which Google uses for all their services. When you first sign in, you have to authorize the registered application (Chrome) to access certain Google APIs in your name. The application then receives a refresh token which can be used to generate an access token. The access token is what lets the application access your data. The refresh token is what Chrome would store somewhere. The original password can't be deducted from the token. Getting access to the token would grant access to the same APIs that Chrome can access.

Comment: A cool way to see OAuth2 work is by using the [Google OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will not store the password, they will store some sort of hash that serves as an authentication token. Sorry!